# Angular 9 + CAS Authentication + .NET Core Web API

Tags: angular, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, cas

My Technology stack is as follows:

- .NET Core Web API (v 2.1)
- Angular 9
- CAS Authentication Server

I am building an intranet application and have the requirement to authenticate users through our CAS Authentication Server. However, I am not quite sure how to glue all the pieces together securely.

After much research, I am unable to find anything similar to what I need to accomplish. This worries me a little -- Am I trying to glue the wrong pieces together? I chose this stack since I have some familiarity with them separately in the past.

So here is what I am thinking I should do:

1. In Angular, check if the user is authenticated. If not, redirect to CAS Authentication endpoint.
2. Once Authenticated with CAS, Angular can intercept the Service Ticket from CAS and pass it to the Web API. Let the Web API determine if the ticket is valid.
3. If the TGT is valid, the Web API issues Angular a JWT, now the front-end and back-end can securely communicate using a JWT.

Is this a valid approach? I am missing something simple when it comes to Angular + Web API + CAS?

Is there a better way? Should I reconsider my technology stack?

I haven't tried to put this in code yet, I want to ensure this approach is secure before I spend time coding it.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working with CAS for a couple of years.
As far as I know, the client-side application (your Angular application) should not be involved with CAS at all.

Applications that I've worked on do the following:

Client requests something from the server - either the Angular application's index.html file. The server determines that the client is not logged in, and redirects the client to the CAS Authentication Server, with a parameter that tells the auth server where to redirect back to after authentication succeeds.

The client's browser is redirected to the CAS Auth Server, the user logs in, and is then redirected back to the server (at the url that was indicated in the parameter in the previous step).

The server now determines that the user is logged in, and redirects to the Angular app's index.html

So, all of the communication is between the server-side app and CAS, and does not go through the Angular app at all.

Comment: This completely makes sense to me if I were using an MVC style web app. The backend server would handle the authentication. However, with Angular + WebAPI these two pieces are independent of each other.

Comment: The client can and should see the Service Ticket, correct?